# ASCII Number to Character Error in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, ascii

I have a problem when I convert ASCII number to character.
I use `chr()` function to convert it to character. I didn't find any errors in a pure PHP page. But, when I use `chr()` function in a web page (using Codeigniter framework) that contains jquery and other javascript, `chr()` function would return an unknown character. 
Here's the example :

```
 chr(218); // It returns `Ú` character in pure PHP page
 chr(218); // It returns `�` character in a complex webpage.
```

Does any one know why is it happen?
And please tell me how fix it!
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you use this?

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >

Comment: I use `<meta charset="utf-8">`, and I put it after `title` tag

Comment: Note that as of this writing, the manual pages for `chr()` and `ord()` misleadingly refer to them in terms of ASCII. PHP's strings are not encoding-aware (and ASCII is a 7-bit encoding in which 218 would be an invalid value anyway). What `chr(218)` actually means is "create a one-byte string whose first and only byte is equivalent to decimal `218`, i.e. hex `DA`, binary `11011010`". How that single-byte string is *interpreted* is entirely up to factors further down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a character encoding problem.

try using

```
iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8', chr(128));
```

to force it to use UTF-8.

This is common if you are returning the value from a function or external script as the encoding isn't always carried over to included files.

Comment: To explain *why* this works: in ISO 8859-1, the single byte character with the decimal position of `218` is the desired character. However, the page you are actually outputting is being interpreted by your browser as UTF-8, which encodes that character as the two bytes `0xC3` and `0x9A`, that is `chr(195) . chr(154)`. This is the conversion `iconv` is performing for you. It has nothing to do with encoding being "carried over", because `chr(128)` contained no encoding information to begin with.

Comment: @IMSoP  Ya. I didn't found any problem when I convert ASCII number to a-z, A-Z, or 0-9.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to set the character encoding of an HTML document

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

---

Reference

[MetaCharsetAttribute](https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute)

---

using php

```
<?php $mysqli->set_charset("utf8") ?>
```

Reference

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Does it must be put at the `head` of HTML?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi yeah even before title tag.You can say at the top in head tag.

Comment: I put it after `title` tag. I'll try

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi put it at top before title tag .

Comment: ya,, I ever use it and it still the same. Btw, i got the answer : Angus Walker's answer
It works well

Comment: The reason this didn't work is that it is actually the opposite of what was required. The desired character is correct only if the browser interprets it as encoded in ISO 8859-1, or some related character set, and *not* as UTF-8. So the actual solution would be to set the charset in the HTML page to *that* encoding (as for MySQL, completely irrelevant here, no database mentioned).